# Re-opening SqlConnection instance

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

1) I noticed that after you close SqlConnection instance, you are still able to re-open the same connection:

a) can you tell me what is going on behind the scenes? Meaning, after we close file stream object, we can’t re-open it, but instead must create a new object – so why isn’t the same with SqlConnection objects?

b) If pooling is enabled, then I assume the connection object is returned back to the connection pool and can later be reused?!

But then how do we know that after re-opening the connection we will get the same Sqlconnection instance as before we initially closed it? I’m asking this because as far as I know, even if connection pool has several connections available, these SqlConnection objects could be in different state than original SqlConnection object ( by “different state” I mean that  some properties  could hold different values than  those in “original” connection object)?!

c) What if pooling isn’t enabled? Does .Net recreate SqlConnection object “from scratch”? 
Again, before we initially closed the SqlConnection object, we might have changed values of some properties? How will compiler know how to recreate the state SqlConnection object was in before we closed it?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

SqlConnection isn't directly the "real" connection in the first place. The connection pool looks after that. I don't know for sure, but I wouldn't be surprised to find that if you reopen the SqlConnection you could end up on a different "physical" network connection.

You could *write* a `FileStream` which allowed reopening - if it kept track of the name of the file as well as the underlying handle, it could just try to reopen it, with all the possible failures etc. It's just not very useful. (I can't say that I find being able to reopen `SqlConnection` useful personally, admittedly.)

In terms of knowing that you'll get "the same `SqlConnection` object" - you aren't calling a method which returns a reference to a `SqlConnection` object, you're just calling a method on an *existing* object. That reference won't change - just the state of the object (or possibly the state of something else it refers to).

I don't know what would happen if pooling weren't enabled. It couldn't create a brand new `SqlConnection` object (or rather it could, but that wouldn't *replace* the one you already had a reference to). I suspect it all boils down to `SqlConnection` being a wrapper around "something else" - and the "something else" could certainly be recreated.